# Наблюдение за изменениями CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, coredata

У меня есть библиотека которая изменяет наблюдателя в `Core Data`

```
[_persistentStore.context
           mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:[[NSNotification alloc]
                                                       initWithName:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification
                                                       object:notification.object userInfo:notification.userInfo]];
```

После чего я начинаю наблюдать за своей базой.

```
notification.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(managedObjectContextObjectsDidChange),
                             name: NSNotification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange, object:nil)
```

Когда добавляется новый объект все хорошо отрабатывает. Но когда происходит обновление объекта. Вместо `updated` или `refreshed` ключа приходит  `invalidatedAll`

Comment: А что делает селектор?

Comment: В селекторе я распечатываю userInfo с данными, которые должны обновляться.